# shift + arrow key

Tags: vbscript

Hi I want to automate the process of selecting some lines from "Personal Communications iSeries Access for Windows". 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/doshI.jpg 
Manually this can be accomplished by:-
1. selecting from mouse (Drag mouse holding LEFT mouse button)
2. Position the cursor and press SHIFT+ARROW keys(UP/DOWN/LEFT/RIGHT).

I tried to do it with VBScript in following way:-

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.SendKeys "{RIGHT 5}"     'Position the cursor
WshShell.SendKeys "+{RIGHT 5}"    'Sending SHIFT+Right Arrow five times
```

But the code for shift+RIGHT Arrow Keys is not working for me. It is writing 66666. Similarly for `WshShell.SendKeys "+{LEFT 5}"`I am getting 44444 as output.

These VBScript sendkeys commands are working fine for other windows applications(like MS Word, Notepad).

Any idea how to proceed?

Answer (score 1):

Try turning NumLock on, then use the arrow keys on the numbers 4 and 6.